# Retain Fragment data without retaining Fragment

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I'm working on an app, which needs to do a lots of calculations in the background.
To do this I start a thread from a fragment and pass a Handler to it, so it can pass messages back. When a configuration change occurs (screen rotation, ...) Android recreates the Activity and Fragment. I'm looking for a way to get a reference to the thread from the new Fragment, so I can pass a new Handler to it.

Retaining the whole Fragment is not an option for me, as it uses a different layout in landscape mode.

I can't use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(), as that is only supported on Activities, but my thread lives in a fragment.

I can't use onSaveInstanceState(), as that only supports primitive data types.

Are there any other ways for me to retain a reference to my background thread when the fragment is recreated?

Comment: Check this if it helps: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

Comment: @DavidK That uses an AsyncTask, while I'm using a Thread. According to the documentation an AsyncTask should "ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)", while my Thread will be running constantly, while the Activity is running.

Comment: Oh I did not know that. Then check one of the on-going Threads, like Executor and similar. Or perhaps try to find some libraries which would handle this well. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a headless retained fragment, which manages the thread.

My normal fragment creates a new instance of the headless fragment, which is retained. The headless fragment has `start()` and `stop()` methods, which in turn start and stop the thread and a `setHandler()` method, which changes the handler messages are passed to.
Whenever the non retained fragment is recreated it just has to get the retained fragment from the FragmentManager and call `setHandler()` with a new Handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ViewModel of android architecture components to do this.

[**Lifecycle aware components:** https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle)

[**Google's ViewModel:** https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)